# How to load image from resource folder and set it to source image of UI Image in unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to load image from resource folder and set that image to source image of UI Image?

Comment: Have a look here [http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/892113/how-can-i-change-a-ui-image-from-a-large-list-of-i.html](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/892113/how-can-i-change-a-ui-image-from-a-large-list-of-i.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Place your sprite in any folder that begins with resources, e.g. mine is in "Resources/Images/test"

```
[SerializeField] private UnityEngine.UI.Image image = null;

private void Awake()
{
    if( image != null )
    {
        image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>( "Images/test" );
    }
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: remember not to include image extension in the resource address.

Answer (score 2):

I try @ananonposter answer but fail.But I try another way by below **code**:

```
var image = new Image();
var tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/transparent");
var sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f,0.0f,tex.width,tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f), 100.0f);
image.sprite = sprite;
```

**It can work!**